# Button returns different value in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a keypad in Kivy, which will insert a number in a TextInput when the corresponding button is pressed.
However, when I press, each button only inserts '8' in the TextInput. I have no idea why this happens.

My code:

```
self.key_pad = GridLayout(rows=3, cols=3, size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 200), pos=(295, 200))
for num in range(9):
    btn = Button(text=str(num), on_press=lambda new_press: self.input_field.insert_text(str(num)))
    self.key_pad.add_widget(btn)
```

Comment: change to `btn = Button(text=str(num), on_press=lambda new_press, num=num: self.input_field.insert_text(str(num)))`

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been stuck on this problem for 4 hours.